# Is there Pandas DataFrame equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python Pandas dataframes to load JSON file in and directly apply several calculation in DF and print out output as JSON.

Now need to port logic to Java.

Is there a Panadas DataFrame equivalent in Java so that can load same JSON file in it and do similar DataFrame calculations (e.g. add column, make first + second column = third column etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: There is a [`spark.sql.DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html), it's not directly equivalent to Pandas but it should be possible to load JSON, add columns, etc.

Comment: You can find specific Java DataFrame equivalent libraries here https://medium.com/@thijser/doing-cool-data-science-in-java-how-3-dataframe-libraries-stack-up-5e6ccb7b437 (tablesaw, joinery, morpheus, datavec)